# spl_autoload_register issue while loading class

Tags: php, spl-autoload-register

So I already asked this question here earlier, but the solutions provided didn't work for me. 
Here's my setup:

```
/mylib
    /Vendor/Module/MyClass.php
/document_root
    index.php
```

Here's my index.php

```
<?php


define('CLASSDIR', 'mylib');
define('BASEPATH',  @realpath( dirname (__FILE__).'/../').'/'.CLASSDIR);

spl_autoload_register(null, false);
spl_autoload_extensions('.php');

function autoLoader($className){

    $className = ltrim($className, '\\');
    $fileName  = '';
    $namespace = '';
    if ($lastNsPos = strrpos($className, '\\')) {
        echo 'does it come here? nope.'; 
        $namespace = substr($className, 0, $lastNsPos);
        $className = substr($className, $lastNsPos + 1);
        $fileName  = str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $namespace) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    }
    $fileName .= BASEPATH.'/'.str_replace('_', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $className) . '.php';

    require $fileName; 
}

spl_autoload_register('autoLoader');

//$obj = new MyClass();

$obj = new \Vendor\Module\MyClass();

$obj::test();

 ?>
```

Here's my MyClass.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module;

class MyClass{

    public function __construct(){
        echo 'weird';
    }

    public function test(){
        echo 'strange';
    }
}
?>
```

None of my echo's display anything. Obviously my class is also not loaded. Instead I get this error.

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method MyClass::test() in /<documentroot>/index.php on line 29
```

Please help. I've been stuck on this for quite a while now and the rest of my development is suffering. I tried moving to `spl_autoload_register()` only because it's the recommended way. Now the lost time is making me regret it.

Comment: Why don't you just use `__autoload()`?

Comment: @ShivanRaptor Because __autoload is supposed to be deprecated. I got that from here - php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php and hence decided to go with spl_autoload_register(). And since this is a new project, I don't want to start using something that I already know is going to get deprecated soon.

Comment: I see. You're correct. I should change my codes too.

Comment: The weird thing is none of the echo statements are firing. Not the autoLoader. Not the constructor. And of course, not the test().

Comment: You need `use Vendor\Module\MyClass` or `new \Vendor\Module\MyClass()`. You haven't told your `index.php` script which namespace `MyClass` is in

Comment: Yes, I did that already as you suggested earlier in your answer below. And only then I got the worsening error messages. See the edit above. It's as if, it's appending the namespace in the front instead of the end. If only it added it to the end, it'd perfectly resolve it. Currently it's looking here :  require(Vendor/Module//mylib/MyClass.php) but it should be looking here:  require(/mylib/Vendor/Module/MyClass.php) as per my original structure in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

F**k yes. Yes, I can take the liberty to swear on a public forum this one time.

A huge shout out to @Shivan Raptor for helping me along the way and not giving up.

There were numerous minor issues in the auto-loader function. But the debugging took me so long for just a simple reason that I couldn't see any echo messages. Only lord and XAMPP knows why. Seemed like XAMPP had somehow cached the class on first run or something and no changes later showed any effect. But creating a new class and class file all of a sudden started showing all my echo including the ones inside autoload. Anyone who has picked up the auto-loader code from the link below, please ensure you look at all the variables' values. It doesn't work "out of the box", if you don't keep everything in the document root. And if you are new to both PSR-0 and concept of auto loading, this can kill at least a sizable portion of your perfectly capable brain cells.

```
https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md
```

Here's the final index.php that worked for me.

```
<?php

define('CLASSDIR', 'mylib');
define('BASEPATH',  @realpath( dirname (__FILE__).'/../').'/'.CLASSDIR);

spl_autoload_register(null, false);
spl_autoload_extensions('.php');

function autoLoader($className){
    $className = ltrim($className, '\\');
    $classPath  = '';
    $namespace = '';
    if ($lastNsPos = strrpos($className, '\\')) {    
        $namespace = substr($className, 0, $lastNsPos);
        $className = substr($className, $lastNsPos + 1);
        $classPath = str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $namespace).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    }
    $fileName = BASEPATH.'/'.$classPath.str_replace('_', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $className).'.php';
    require $fileName;
}

spl_autoload_register('autoLoader');

$obj = new \Vendor\Module\MyClass();
$obj::test();
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

Your are calling the `test()` function incorrectly (using static way?).

Call the function with:

```
$obj = new MyClass();
$obj->test();
```

If you intend to use static method like `MyClass::test()`, declare your function in your class as:

```
public static function test() {
}
```

---

Moreover, your autoloader is over-complicated. It can be simplified as:

```
$class_dir = array(
    '/mylib/Vendor/Module/',
    // Add more paths here ( or you can build your own $class_dir )
);

function class_loader($class_name) {
    global $class_dir;
    foreach ($class_dir as $directory) {
        if (file_exists($directory . $class_name . '.php')) {
            require_once($directory . $class_name . '.php');
            return;
        }
    }
}
spl_autoload_register('class_loader');
```

---

**3rd edit:**

I noticed the path you set is incorrect.

```
$fileName .= BASEPATH.'/'.str_replace('_', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $className) . '.php';
```

It should be:

```
$filename = BASEPATH .'/' . $filename . str_replace('_', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $className) . '.php';
```

As said before, it can be easily debugged by echoing the value of `$filename`.