# How to definitively determine if an object was instantiated

Tags: php, namespaces, spl-autoload-register

I have a PHP class which I'm instantiating an object for. If I change the namespace of the class of change the path of the class, the autoloader complains that that class is not defined. But when I do everything correctly, there are no complaints but the echo in the constructor is not triggered. So I'm assuming it found the class, but then why is the constructor code not triggered? How can I definitely tell that an object has been instantiated?

```
$obj = new MyClass()?
```

How to check whether $obj is instantiated properly?

For the original question, please see here. [spl_autoload_register issue while loading class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19556728/spl-autoload-register-issue-while-loading-class)

Any answers you can provide there is also highly appreciated. I'm trying to break a bigger problem into several smaller ones to solve it.

Comment: Maybe the autoloader found an other file with the same class name.

Comment: No, this is a clean new project. There are no other files yet. The folders are basically empty other than one index.php and one MyClass.php.